# antiderivative of $\sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty }{ (n+1){ x }^{ 2n+2 } } $

Tags: calculus, power-series

I've proven that the radius of convergence of  $\sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty  }{ (n+1){ x }^{ 2n+2 } } $ is $R=1$, and that it doesn't converge at the edges.

Now, I was told that this is the derivative of a function $f(x)$, which holds $f(0)=0$.

My next step is to find this function in simple terms, and here I get lost. My attempt:

$f(x)=\sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { n+1 }{ 2n+3 } { x }^{ 2n+3 } }  $

and this doesn't seem to help.

I'd like to use the fact that $|x|<1$ so I'll get a nice sum based on the sum of a geometric series but I have those irritating coefficients.

Any tips?

Comment: this appears to be an Arithmetico Geometric series (AGP)

Comment: you have $\displaystyle{f'(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}(n+1)(x^2)^{n+1}}$, so you just need to express $\displaystyle{g(x)=\sum_{n\geq1}n\ x^n}$.

Comment: Adding to @Taladris comment that, $\sum_{1}^{\infty}z^n=\frac{z}{1-z}\implies \sum_{1}^{\infty}nz^{n-1}=\frac{d}{dz}\frac{z}{1-z}$ solves your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, consider
$$
g(w)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)w^n.
$$
Integrating term-by-term, we find that the antiderivative $G(w)$ for $g(w)$ is
$$
G(w):=\int g(w)\,dw=C+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}w^{n+1}
$$
where $C$ is an arbitrary constant. To make $g(0)=0$, we take $C=0$; then
$$
G(w)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}w^{n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}w^n=\frac{w}{1-w}\qquad\text{if}\qquad\lvert w\rvert<1.
$$
(Here, we've used that this last is a geometric series with first term $w$ and common ratio $w$.) So, we find
$$
g(w)=G'(w)=\frac{1}{(1-w)^2},\qquad \lvert w\rvert<1.
$$
Now, how does this relate to the problem at hand? Note that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^{2n+2}=x^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)(x^2)^n=x^2g(x^2)=\frac{x^2}{(1-x^2)^2}
$$
as long as $\lvert x^2\vert<1$, or equivalently $\lvert x\rvert <1$.

From here, you can finish your exercise by integrating this last function with respect to $x$, and choosing the constant of integration that makes its graph pass through $(0,0)$.

Comment: I thought he was looking for a closed form for the integral of that sum. But yes.

Comment: I interpreted his question as "use the fact that this is the derivative of a nice function to find a closed form for this series."  Tomato, tomato.

Comment: So now I just integrate that last fraction with $c=0$, right?

Comment: Yeah, the question is a bit unclear. I don't think "tomato, tomato" is an apt quote, however, because our interpretations are pretty different, while that phrase is used to mean two things that are pronounced differently but mean the same thing... :)

Comment: @Paz Can you please clarify: what exactly are you asked to find?  A closed form for the power series, a closed form for its indefinite integral, or an exact value for some definite integral?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I only meant that he's within spitting distance of the solution to EITHER problem at this point. :-)

Comment: @nrpeterson A closed form for its indefinite integral.

Comment: @Paz then yes, you can finish by integrating that last expression, and finding the constant of integration that makes it pass through $(0,0)$.

Comment: @nrpeterson Great. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\frac{n+1}{2n+3} = \frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{2n+3}\right)$$